# How does one strengthen the muscle connected to the lower end of the scapula?

Tags: position, shoulder, physical-therapy, scoliosis, scapula

I was so addicted to Tetris in college (playing several hours every day with my left hand farther forward on the keyboard than my right) that my left back visibly atrophied in the region surrounding the bottom of its scapula. After that I was found to have scoliosis for the first time in my life. Back pain ensued.

Now when I raise a weight over my head with both hands, I can feel my left shoulder blade poking out more than my right. It also takes conscious effort to keep my left shoulder down and back when I'm doing push-ups. My physical therapist says that when I lie down on my stomach my scoliosis almost completely vanishes, but when I stand up (which is when I feel the tension back there) it comes back and pulls to the right between the shoulder blades.

I'd like to correct this. A year of chin-ups didn't seem to do the trick. Any tips?

Comment: What did the physical therapist say about your scapula?  You're asking how to strengthen the muscles that keep the scapula flat on the back when we don't know what's actually wrong - while your PT is the one who has examined you, and that's their area of expertise.

Comment: I say that because there are multiple things that can cause what you describe.  Winged scapula is a nerve issue, atrophy from disuse is fundamentally muscular, it could be something related to your scoliosis, etc.